# Rename title of @@personal-information

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I want to change the tab's title from "Personal information" to "Personal settings" in all related sections like site/@@personal-information and site/@@personal-preferences

Any idea where I can set it?
Or is it OK to solve it with Diazo or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did a JS-solution once, when the usecase was for a handful of content-managers who certainly would not disable Javascript.

To be compliant with the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG), you want to [override](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/i18n/internationalisation.html#overriding-translations) the English translation-string of Plone.

Hint: A translation for "Personal Information" occurs twice in `plone.pot`, you need to regard two message-ids.